# So im trying to get the corresponeding value of the first generic value in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

According to api docs:

> Object with key-value pairs where key is notif ID and value is
> username

```
"username_map": {
            "5102731": "cys",
            "142023": "kam",
            "326403": "Jif",
            "238109": "asgs",
            "2441222": "Okto",
            ...
        },
```

(This is the reply of the api)

If i have the user id for example 142023 then how can i get the name "kam"?

First i have to set the type ofcourse.

i was thinking maybe it is:

```
 ArrayList<Pair<Integer,String>> username_map;
```

then in the code

```
String username = username_map.getFirst(userIdInt)
```

But it didnt work.

For the correct type, how would i get the corresponding value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON String to List of Java Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237428/convert-json-string-to-list-of-java-objects)

Comment: not really because it doesnt tell me what Type i need to set and also im not sure but his values dont seem generic and the answers dont help aswell

Comment: Try to use `Map`, something like this : `Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();` after filling it using `data.put()`, then you can try `String username = data.get(userId);`

Comment: Mouaad your a king. It worked. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Mouaad from the comment helped me to solve this!

What i did in the model of the api:

```
Map<Integer, String> username_map;

   public Map<Integer, String> getUsername_map() {
       return username_map;
   }
```

And then in the code:

```
  Map<Integer, String> username_map = response.body().getData().getUsername_map();
    int uid = (any user id)
    username_map.get(uid)
```